# Xamarin android filter recyclerview data

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-filter

i am currently working with recyclerview in Xamarin android where i wish to filter the data displayed. I used to work with java on android and has successfully create a filter on recyclerview with using searchview. But for this one , i wish to display only the incomplete data where either one of the item in the view is empty. Below is my code for activity class and also recyclerview adapter class.Replies with code or explanation would be really helpful. Thank you.

```
class RemoveAlertActivity : Activity
{

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView_remove;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager_remove;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter_remove;
    private List<Removerecyclerholder> mRemoverecyclerholder;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RemoveAlert);

        SQLiteDb obj = new SQLiteDb();
        List<ScanSummary> scan = new List<ScanSummary>();
        scan = obj.GetAllScanSummaryData();
        ScanSummary[] array = scan.ToArray();
        mRemoverecyclerholder = new List<Removerecyclerholder>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
                mRemoverecyclerholder.Add(new Removerecyclerholder() { partnumber_r = scan[i].SSPartNo, containernumber_r = scan[i].SSContainerSN, scanquantity_r = scan[i].SSPackType, totalquantity_r = scan[i].SSStatus });

        }
        mRecyclerView_remove = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerview_remove);
        mLayoutManager_remove = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView_remove.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager_remove);
        mAdapter_remove = new RecyclerAdapter_remove(mRemoverecyclerholder);
        mRecyclerView_remove.SetAdapter(mAdapter_remove);
    }

}
public class RecyclerAdapter_remove : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private List<Removerecyclerholder> mRemoverecyclerholder;


    public RecyclerAdapter_remove(List<Removerecyclerholder> removerecyclerholder)
    {
        mRemoverecyclerholder = removerecyclerholder;
    }
    public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View mMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView mpartnumber_r { get; set; }
        public TextView mcontainernumber_r { get; set; }
        public TextView mtotalquantity_r { get; set; }
        public TextView mscanquantity_r { get; set; }

        public MyView(View view) : base(view)
        {
            mMainView = view;
        }
    }
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {

        SQLiteDb obj = new SQLiteDb();
        List<ScanSummary> scan = obj.GetAllScanSummaryData();

        View RemoveRecycleLayout = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.RemoveAlertRecycleLayout, parent, false);
        TextView txtpartnumber_r = RemoveRecycleLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.partnumber_remove);
        TextView txtcontainernumber_r = RemoveRecycleLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.containernumber_remove);
        TextView txttotalquantity_r = RemoveRecycleLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.totalquantity_remove);
        TextView txtscanquantity_r = RemoveRecycleLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.scanquantity_remove);


        MyView view = new MyView(RemoveRecycleLayout) { mpartnumber_r = txtpartnumber_r, mcontainernumber_r = txtcontainernumber_r, mtotalquantity_r = txttotalquantity_r, mscanquantity_r = txtscanquantity_r };

        return view;
    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        MyView myholder = holder as MyView;
        myholder.mpartnumber_r.Text = mRemoverecyclerholder[position].partnumber_r;
        myholder.mcontainernumber_r.Text = mRemoverecyclerholder[position].containernumber_r;
        myholder.mtotalquantity_r.Text = mRemoverecyclerholder[position].totalquantity_r;
        myholder.mscanquantity_r.Text = mRemoverecyclerholder[position].scanquantity_r;

        ((MyView)holder).mMainView.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            View mMainView = (View)sender;
            mMainView.SetBackgroundColor(color: Color.Blue);
            var activity = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(RemoveDataDetails));
            activity.PutExtra("partnumber_r", mRemoverecyclerholder[position].partnumber_r);
            activity.PutExtra("containernumber_r", mRemoverecyclerholder[position].containernumber_r);
            Application.Context.StartActivity(activity);
        };

    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mRemoverecyclerholder.Count; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Not quite understand where the problem is?

Comment: i dont have any problem with the current code, it's just now i need to create a filter function for filtering my recyclerview to display only incomplete data and i dont have idea on how to work on it. In the past i did do a filter function using search view, but for this one what i wish to do is just to display the incomplete recyclerview data instead of all data.

Comment: Would you share your full code? Then it would be more easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, actually this is my full code expect code for my layout and recyclerview holder. I actually managed to solved it using another method which i filter it in my sqlite data where i put a status for my table and then I filter using the status. By the way, thank you for your response.